# How to redirect to a URL on selecting an option from a dynamically-filled dependent drop-down list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, select, drop-down-menu

I have created three-level dependent dropdown lists. What I don't seem to find an answer for is how should I go about redirecting the user to a certain URL for every option on the third dropdown list?

```html
 <select id="models-select" onchange="updateConfigurations()">
 <option value="" disabled selected> Select Area </option>
 </select>

 <select id="configurations-select">
 <option value="" disabled selected> Select Configuration</option>
 </select>
```

JS:

````
  ```javascript
  function createConfiguration(name, id, model) {
  return {
    name: name,
    id: id,
    model: model,
    }

var configurations = [
createConfiguration('M6', 'm6', 'BMW')```
````

How can I combine select id with onchange to include the URL?

Comment: Yes. Just add an onchange to the last one. If you click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56292723/edit) and then `[<>]` snippet editor you can provide us with a [mcve]

Comment: I just did. Thanks, I know can do that, but I can't get to understand how to change the JS function to include the URL and fetch it.

Comment: Update your question with relevant html